# Texmaker ignores whitespace "\:" in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, white-space

I'm using TexMaker to compile a document. I need to display many physical quantities, i.e., numbers with whitespace and then some units. The way I try to do it is like this:
`$13 \: \rm unit$`.
I want to include the unit in the math expression as otherwise, sometimes it is not on the same line any more. However, while most of the time it works, sometimes, the whitespace is just ignored. There is simply no whitespace (not even a smaller one) between the number and the unit.
I use PDFLaTeX to compile it and the following packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[font={small},width={.9\linewidth}]{caption}
```

Any ideas?
If this is the wrong way to do it, of course, I would also be grateful for any tips on how to do it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A better spacing command would be `\,`. But you should really use a specialized package such as `siunitx`. Beware that `\rm` has been deprecated for 25 years.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You'd better  type numbers with units  using the `\SI` command from `siunitx` anyway. The symbols and spacings will be correct

Comment: Not related, but `hyperref` package should be loaded last in (your) preamble.